# Shelling out to a program without it appearing

Tags: c#

How can I shell out to a DOS application in VB.NET/C# and it not flash on screen.  I rather it not appear because it flashes, it opens and then terminates after doing its processing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the process window, why isn't it working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246613/hiding-the-process-window-why-isnt-it-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this useful [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process). Quoted below:

```
static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
{
    // For the example.
    const string ex1 = "C:\\";
    const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";

    // Use ProcessStartInfo class.
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "dcm2jpg.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using-statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error?
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;` be `true`?

Comment: Seems like `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` does the same thing. Some applications may want a window to exist somewhere... I'd advise manipulating those settings until it works the exact way you want it to work. My answer was only meant to provide a means for accessing the process settings.

Comment: Awesome, the WindowStyle fixed it.  No more hard to stop the app when things going wrong :)  Regards MiscellaneousUser a.k.a. Agent 005